# how to listen to the change of specific map with firebase cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

hello i have this as my Firebase Firestore structure :

[image: Firestore]

i have a little problem which is that i want to listen to changes that happens to the map `0` , i already know how to listen to a specific document with the `onCreate` method , but not a field , any suggestions ?

also how can i add any data to the map 0 inside posts array  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the minimal entity you can listen to is a `document`. That means you can't setup a Firebase Cloud Function trigger if just a `Field` of a document changes.

To update the `[0]` you would need to get the whole Array, change it and save again the whole array. There is also another way to do it. You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073).